# Installing CiviCRM on a Drupal 9 site with Drush 11 conflict due to symfony/filesystem ~4.4 requirement

Tags: drupal-9, composer

Currently if you install Drupal 9, Drush then CiviCRM you end up with a Composer "Problem" due to Drush requiring consolidation/site-alias (^3.1.6 || ^4) and composer picking the v4 version which then requires consolidation/site-alias 4.0.0  requires symfony/filesystem (^5.4 || ^6)

Answer (score 2):

The solution here is to either install CiviCRM before drush - or if installing on an existing site or if that fails you can help composer pick the right version

via
composer  require civicrm/civicrm-{core,packages,drupal-8}:"5.55.1"  "consolidation/site-alias:^3.1.6" -W